# Defining my own operator that Simplify will recognize

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I would like to define my own operator and have Mathematica simplify expressions using it. Say I have an operator

$\qquad P = \frac{d}{dt} + f(x,t)\frac{d}{dx}$

and I have an expression like

$\qquad (\frac{dw}{dt} + f(x,t)\frac{dw}{dx})(1 + \frac{dq}{dt} + f(x,t)\frac{dq}{dx})$,

how can I get Mathematica to simplify this to

$\qquad (P\,w)(1 + P\,q)$?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
rule = Times[f[x, t], 
    Derivative[1, 0][y_][x, t]] :> (P[y] - D[y[x, t], t]);
```

If this is your expression,

```
A = (D[w[x, t], t]+f[x, t]*D[w[x, t], x])*(1 + (D[q[x, t], t] +f[x, t]*D[q[x, t], x]));
```

you can use

```
A /. rule

(*   (1 + P[q]) P[w]   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! It's working well